# MVC4 Extend SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am looking at migrating an old app to MVC4 but can't yet modify the database. The existing database already has it's own user / group / membership tables setup (in a rather quirky way might I add, but it works).

With the MVC3 style MembershipProviders I could roll my own extending what I needed to login, check role permissions, modify user attributes etc. but I'm at a loss as to how to achieve this with MVC4 and it's SimpleMembership and then how to use OpenAuth alongside it as an alternate way to login.

I've been looking around but there seems to be very little content online yet regarding it, any ideas?

I don't require a SimpleMembership implementation, if anyone is aware of another similar provider that would do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleMembership is just like its name: simple. So if you want to extend the membership provider to meet your complex requirement of roles and membership, it's not a good choice. If you do really have to upgrade your app to mvc4, just do it, then reuse the ASP.Net Membership that exited in your app. It's still running properly on mvc4.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is to just use SimpleMembership and add as many roles as you need to make up for your current "attributes".  Depends on what you mean by "attributes".  If you just want to add additional columns to the UsersProfile table, it's pretty easy to do.  And then the SimpleMembership API can access those new columns just as it does the built-in ones in a default MVC4 Internet App. project.

Have you viewed [this SO thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435252/how-to-create-custom-additional-fields-in-userprofile-in-mvc4)