# .net MVC Simple Membership Authentication with Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, entity-framework-4, membership-provider

Using Code First Entity Framework with .NET MVC 4 I have created a new Web Application and populated the database with object as shown below.

```
 public class GratifyGamingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserRepository { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use my UserRepository table instead of the inbuilt UserContext class from AccountModel.cs for my user account access since I can't get that the work with my existing dbContext.

```
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

My program always crashes when constructing a SimpleMembershipInitializer object from InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs. I have commented out the code I feel should be irrelevant.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new GratifyGamingContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ConnectionString is as follows:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GratifyGaming-20120917185558;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Games.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get the following error when calling the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnect from any AccountController page:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Directory lookup for the file
> "C:\Users\Unreal\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2010\Projects\GratifyGaming\GratifyGaming.WebUI\App_Data\Games.mdf"
> failed with the operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for
> this error. Reason: 15105). Cannot attach the file
> 'C:\Users\Unreal\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2010\Projects\GratifyGaming\GratifyGaming.WebUI\App_Data\Games.mdf' as
> database 'aspnet-GratifyGaming-20120917185558'.]
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
> an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
> type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
> RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0

My application is otherwise connected to the database if I do not go to any AccountController driven page.
How can I configure this application to use my UserRepository table instead of the UsersContext for user membership?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove the AttachDbFileName from the DefaultConnectionString in web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GratifyGaming-20120917185558;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Call the WebSecurity.InitialiseDatabase method in Global.asax.cs

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        Database.SetInitializer<GratifyGamingContext>(new DatabaseInitializer()); 
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                  connectionStringName: "DefaultConnection",
                  userTableName: "UserProfile",
                  userIdColumn: "UserID",
                  userNameColumn: "UserName",
                  autoCreateTables: true);
    }
}
```

Comment out [InitializeSimpleMembership] in AccountController.cs

```
 [Authorize]
    //[InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
```

Comment: Found this out after reading a couple of stackoverflow posts that covered different components of the issue.

Comment: So we don't need `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` any more?

Comment: Here's another answer to this question that may help some people: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12461447/188246 (slightly different than the answer above)

Comment: @Ashkan You do need the InitializeSimpleMembership if you're still using the default tables.