# EntityCodeFirst + MVC4 WebSecurity = Sad Me

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, security, code-first

Coming from [This Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435252/how-to-create-custom-additional-fields-in-userprofile-in-mvc4)
I have a data context

```
public class AggregateContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlogEntry> BlogEntries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

And in app start I have this

```
        Database.SetInitializer(new TestingDbInitializer());
        new AggregateContext().UserProfiles.Find(1);
```

And my Initializer looks like this

```
  public class TestingDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AggregateContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(AggregateContext context)
    {
        AccountsContext(context);
        // add a bunch of Lorems to the blog. does call context.SaveChanges();
        BlogsContext(context);
    }

    void AccountsContext(AggregateContext context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            "DefaultConnection",
            "UserProfile",
            "UserId",
            "UserName",
            autoCreateTables: true);

        //create Admin
        if (!WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount("Admin"))
        {
            var confirm = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                "Admin",
                "password",
                new { Email = "please@help.me" });

            if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
                Roles.CreateRole("Admin");

            Roles.AddUserToRole("Admin", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

When I run it I crash on this line.

> var confirm = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
>                       "Admin",
>                       "password",
>                       new { Email = "please@help.me" });

with the sqlexception "Invalid column name 'Email'."
Looking at my database in server explorer I see that the email column was not created.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AggregateContext : DbContext
{
    public AggregateContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<BlogEntry> BlogEntries { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Forgot to define the connection. Go Me !