# Add user when account is created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, account, user-profile

I am using an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application, internet application template.

I have coded my own User object and wish to associate this User object when an Account is created.

I am not sure exactly how to do this. Here is what I have done so far:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Where/how should I setup my own User object when an account is created?

Comment: You should have a controller like Users or Account with a method like SignIn or CreateAccount. Put your logic there.

Comment: This link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435252/how-to-create-custom-additional-fields-in-userprofile-in-mvc4